# How to setup group for Exchange 2013 forwarding?

Tags: exchange-2013

I've got a user who left the company, but we need to keep the address and account alive because of reasons.  Currently I've got that account set to forward e-mail to another individual account and that works fine.  However, there are now multiple people that need to receive those forwards.  The Exchange forwarder box only allows for *one* target address.

The various instructions online all said that I could create a Universal Distribution Group and use that as the forward target (with my real target addresses as members).  No problems creating the group.  However, Exchange never sees it.  It simply does not ever show up in the list of available forwarding targets (and I've waiting a full 24 hours in case 2013 still requires those overnight GAL updates).

Interestingly, *other* old Universal Distribution Groups *do* show up in the Exchange forwarder availability list.  I can't figure out what the difference is though.  Strongly tempted to repurpose one of those if I can just to get this working, but there's got to be a real fix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure it's mail enabled distribution group, run below command to check:

> Get-DistributionGroup  | FL Name,GroupType,RecipientType*

It should be **MailUniversalDistributionGroup**.

Comment: Aha.  My Exchange setup knowledge is dated it seems.  I'm used to the old days of setting up distribution groups in AD and Exchange automatically seeing them.  Creating it in EAC under groups adds the magic MailUniversalDistributionGroup piece that I was missing!